# Servlet not redirecting to jsp properly

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have an Ajax call to a servlet on the `$(document).ready` function.
After all operations made, the servlet tries to redirect the request and response to a page:

```
try {
    request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
    return;
} catch (ServletException| IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The servlet is running, cause I can see everything on the log, but on my jsp page all the attributes are null.

On the servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("test", 1);
```

On the index.jsp:

```
${test}
```

It prints nothing.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

In a JSP file, JSTL expressions (`${...}`) can only access *variables*. You must first *load* your request attribute with :

```
<jsp:useBean id="test" scope="request" class="java.lang.String" />
```

And then you can successfully use  `${test}`

Comment: Now it`s not loading the jsp and it gives me this error: `The value for the useBean class attribute java.lang.Integer is invalid.`

Comment: @AndreDuarte: My bad ... I forgot that the class in `<jsp:useBean .../>` should have a default constructor :-( - post edited.